# How to change the default width (180px) css for the class of `.mat-form-field-infix` in angular-material 8?

Tags: css, sass, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I am using angular-material 8, I need to reduce the default width (180px) of the `.mat-form-field-infix`, but am unable to change that css?

This is the by default-size of the `.mat-form-field-infix`:[default-size field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVxy4.png)

I need like this filed exact with the text.[I need exact like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCfgP.png)

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dednjkjobqj) example reference link, i need to reduce the size of the select field width.

How can I do that changes, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **style.css** add

```
.mat-form-field-infix {
 width: 100px !important;
}
```

[stacblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jczqzm?file=styles.css)

Comment: Add whatever `width` you want and make sure to add `!important` in every property.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to specifically set .mat-form-field-infix width when you can more easily control width on mat-form-field?:

```
mat-form-field {
    width: 100px;
}
```